# Only display posts with a specific tag

Tags: tags

How can I only display posts with a specific tag? This is my loop:

```
<?php 
    if ( have_posts() ) { 
        while ( have_posts() ) { 
            the_post(); 
            get_template_part( 'entry' ); 
            comments_template(); 
            }
        }
?>
```

I've tried a lot of different things but can't seem to figure it out. I also think I'm missing something vital with how PHP and Wordpress work.

Should I use [is_tag](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_tag/#source-code) and if so, how?

EDIT:

I want to show three columns with posts on the front page (index) each column showing only posts with a specific tag, which is unique for each column. Something like:

| column1 tag1 | column2 tag2 | column3 tag3 |

Thanks in advance!

**Sollution with help from Blaine:**

```
<div style="background-color:blue;width:33%;float:right;">
    <?php
        $right = new WP_Query( array(
           'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'no_found_rows'  => true,
            'tag'            => 'right'
        ) );
        if ( $right->have_posts() ) :

            while ( $right->have_posts() ) : $right->the_post();

            the_post(); 
            get_template_part( 'entry' ); 
            comments_template(); 

        endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();

        endif;
    ?>
</div>

<div style="background-color:green;width:33%;float:right;">
    <?php
        $middle = new WP_Query( array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'no_found_rows'  => true,
            'tag'            => 'middle'
        ) );

        if ( $middle->have_posts() ) :

            while ( $middle->have_posts() ) : $middle->the_post();

            the_post(); 
            get_template_part( 'entry' ); 
            comments_template(); 

            endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();

        endif;
    ?>
</div>

<div style="background-color:yellow;width:33%;">
    <?php
        $left = new WP_Query( array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'no_found_rows'  => true,
            'tag'            => 'left'
        ) );

        if ( $left->have_posts() ) :

            while ( $left->have_posts() ) : $left->the_post();

            the_post(); 
            get_template_part( 'entry' ); 
            comments_template(); 

            endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();

        endif;
    ?>
</div>
```

I put this code into my index.php and it works like a charm :)

Comment: Where do you want to only display posts with a specific tag, on the home page, archives, ... or somewhere else ?

Comment: I want to have three columns on the index-page. Each column containing post from one specific tag, unique to that column. Like: | colum1 tag1 | column2 tag2 | column3 tag3 |

Comment: That's a very different question from the one you asked - update your original question with the information you just posted!

Comment: Is it? Though it didn't matter where or how the selection were used. Will update!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [tag parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters) of the [WP_Query class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

You'll most likely need to create three separate queries.

```
<?php
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'no_found_rows'  => true,
    'tag'            => 'tag1'
) );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) :

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

        // the_title();

    endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();

endif; ?>
```